# no such table: Append_employeemodel Django

Tags: django, api, django-models, django-rest-framework

## [**GitHub repository**](https://github.com/brijesh-kalkani/append)

When I send a post request I get this.

[image]

**I previously try**

```
python manage.py syncdb   
./manage.py migrate 
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py createsuperuser
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

but I still got an error. The Git Hub link is above please help me.

Comment: do not set link to your repository but rather write https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @iklinac thank you  for your valuable time

Answer (score 1):

Django looks for models in a `models.py` file or `models` directory, not ['model.py'](https://github.com/brijesh-kalkani/append/blob/master/Append/model.py).

I'd strongly suggest you use [`django-admin startproject name [directory]`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/django-admin/#startproject) when creating new projects or [`django-admin startapp name [directory]`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/django-admin/#startapp) when creating new apps in order for a consistent directory structure to be generated.

Also try and follow the naming conventions in Django. For example `employeeModel` could rather be `Employee`, `empName` rather `employee_name`,  `TradeInfo` rather `trade_info`, etc.